# TypeScript Error in Vuex Module - Something wrong that sub-module is unable to assign into index Module of Vuex

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm building a simple vue-project using TypeScript.
I wrote the vuex store in my vue project, and the store has a sub-module called 'calculation'. But once created the main store including sub-module, a weird error (tserror) occurs.

Following is my vuex code.

```
// calculation.ts
import { Module } from 'vuex'

interface ICalculationState {
  a: number
}

const calculation: Module<ICalculationState, {}> = {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    a: 10
  }
}

export {
  calculation,
  ICalculationState
}
```

```
// index.ts
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import { calculation, ICalculationState } from './calculation'

Vue.use(Vuex)

interface IState {
  calculation: ICalculationState
}

const store = new Vuex.Store<IState>({
  modules: {
    calculation
  }
})

export { store, IState }
```

Error string

```
Type '{ calculation: Module<ICalculationState, {}>; }' is not assignable to type 'ModuleTree<IState>'.
  Property 'calculation' is incompatible with index signature.
  Type 'Module<ICalculationState, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Module<any, IState>'.
  Types of property 'actions' are incompatible.
  Type 'ActionTree<ICalculationState, {}> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ActionTree<any, IState> | undefined'.
  Type 'ActionTree<ICalculationState, {}>' is not assignable to type 'ActionTree<any, IState>'.
  Index signatures are incompatible.
  Type 'Action<ICalculationState, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Action<any, IState>'.
  Type 'ActionHandler<ICalculationState, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Action<any, IState>'.
  Type 'ActionHandler<ICalculationState, {}>' is not assignable to type 'ActionHandler<any, IState>'.
  The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
  Type 'Store<IState>' is not assignable to type 'Store<{}>'.
  Types of property 'registerModule' are incompatible.
  Type '{ <T>(path: string, module: Module<T, IState>, options?: ModuleOptions | undefined): void; <T>(path: string[], module: Module<T, IState>, options?: ModuleOptions | undefined): void; }' is not assignable to type '{ <T>(path: string, module: Module<T, {}>, options?: ModuleOptions | undefined): void; <T>(path: string[], module: Module<T, {}>, options?: ModuleOptions | undefined): void; }'.
  Types of parameters 'module' and 'module' are incompatible.
  Type 'Module<any, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Module<any, IState>'.
  Types of property 'actions' are incompatible.
  Type 'ActionTree<any, {}> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ActionTree<any, IState> | undefined'.
  Type 'ActionTree<any, {}>' is not assignable to type 'ActionTree<any, IState>'.
  Index signatures are incompatible.
  Type 'Action<any, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Action<any, IState>'.
  Type 'ActionHandler<any, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Action<any, IState>'.
  Type 'ActionHandler<any, {}>' is not assignable to type 'ActionHandler<any, IState>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IState'.ts(2322)
index.ts(9, 3): 'calculation' is declared here.
index.d.ts(95, 3): The expected type comes from property 'modules' which is declared here on type 'StoreOptions<IState>'
```

I want the **red-underline** to disappear from beneath line of where my code is.

Answer (score 2):

In calculation.ts provide IState as second parameter in "Module".
By this way you define your root state and the error is gone.

```
const calculation: Module<ICalculationState, IState>
```